# How to style an element in a 3 level superfish menu

Tags: css, css-selectors, superfish

I have a superfish vertical menu for a three level hierarchy.

```
  Level-1     Level-2    Level-3    
  Fruit       Apples     Green
```

The link text color is red on a white background. When I hover down to the third level item(Green) and the menu expands, I want the active path (top, mid, and bottom selected path levels) to invert to white text on a red background. Flipping the selected link (green) is easy using a:hover, and somehow the background flips at Apples and Fruit, but the text remains red and is no longer readable. How do I select Fruit and Apples to control their text color?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
This is a drupal implementation of superfish, but I don't think that matters.
The css is defined by

```
a {color:red; background-color:white;}
```

and the hover condition is addressed in the following

```
.sf-menu li:active, /* no effect from this line*/
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li:focus,/* no effect from this line*/
.sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu li:active a,
.sf-menu a:focus,
.sf-menu a:hover,
.sf-menu a:active {
  background: red; /*Hover background */
   color: white; 
}
```

There is also other classes and settings injected by Superfly that modify margins, but padding and position settings for various conditions, but none addressing color.  As best I can tell, the superfly menu works using js to show hidden menu sections at when the user hovers over an item.  But I cannot determine how it is managing to keep the fruit background red when I hover on apple or green, but not change the text color.

Here is an actual html cascade for a menu display

```
<ul id="superfish-3" class="menu sf-menu sf-menu-materials sf-vertical sf-style-MatMenu2 sf-total-items-23 sf-parent-items-22 sf-single-items-1 superfish-processed sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
  <li id="menu-899-3" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children">
    <li id="menu-900-3" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-8 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-8 menuparent">
     <a class="sf-depth-1 menuparent sf-with-ul" title="FRUIT" href="/specs/03">
       FRUIT
         <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span>
     </a>
       <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden; float: none; width: 12em;">
         <li id="menu-901-3" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
           <a class="sf-depth-2 " title="**APPLE**" href="/specs/031000" style="float: none; width: auto;">APPLE</a>
        </li>
```

As You can see, a lot of classes are defined.  And like I said, I am confused why the hover background color still applies to the parent, but the text color goes back to the not hover display. I'm just trying to find a class that might select the parent of the hover item and keep the text in the hover condition (white).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a link to your site?

As a guess out of the box try:

```
/* 3rd level links, no hover */
    .sf-menu li li li a, .sf-menu li.sfHover li li a {
        color: white;


    }

/* 3rd level links, hover */
.sf-menu li li li a:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover li li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

It can be tricky to sort out the styling for this, but I find that using this can help. It styles up the menu in hideous colours, but gives you a good chance at getting to grips with the CSS. Let me know how you get on:

EDIT: This for horizontal menus:

```
/*** COLOR SKIN ***/

/* main ul element */
.sf-menu {
    border-right: 1px solid FUCHSIA;
    float:left;
}

/* general link styles*/
.sf-menu a {
    display: block;
    padding:9px 13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

/*** 1st Level ***/

/* 1st level links, no hover, no visits */
.sf-menu li a {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: red;
}
/* 1st level links, while hovering over sub menu */
.sf-menu li.sfHover a{
    color: black;
    background-color: silver;
}

/* 1st level links, hover */
.sf-menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: lime;
}

/* 1st level current page */
.sf-menu .current_page_item a,
.sf-menu .current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu .current_page_parent a {
    border-bottom-color: white;
    background-color: TEAL;
}

/* 1st level down triangles with pure css*/
.sf-menu li .sf-sub-indicator {
    text-indent:-9999px;
    line-height: 0;
    border-color:YELLOW transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:4px; /*controls size of triangle */
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}

/*** 2nd level ***/

/* sub menu */
.sf-menu ul {
    border-right:1px solid;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    border-color: yellow;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
    top:32px; /* overriding essential styles- adjust if you have gaps between first level and drop-down sub menu*/
}
.sf-menu ul ul {
    margin-top:0; /*unlikely to need adjusting */
}

/* 2nd level links, no hover */
.sf-menu li li a, .sf-menu li.sfHover li a {
    color: orange;
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: green;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

/* 2nd level links, while hovering over sub menu */
.sf-menu li li.sfHover a{
    color: black;
    background-color: silver;
}

/* 2nd level links, hover */
.sf-menu li li a:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: aqua;
}

/* 2nd level current page */
.sf-menu li li.current_page_item a,
.sf-menu li li.current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu li li.current_page_parent a {
    background-color: TEAL;
}

/* 2nd level side triangles with pure CSS */
.sf-menu li li .sf-sub-indicator { /*right arrow*/
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent WHITE;
}

/*** 3rd Level and beyond ***/

/* 3rd level links, no hover */
.sf-menu li li li a, .sf-menu li.sfHover li li a {
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: blue;
}

/* 3rd level links, hover */
.sf-menu li li li a:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover li li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: pink;
}

/* 2nd level current page */
.sf-menu li li li.current_page_item a,
.sf-menu li li li.current_page_ancestor a,
.sf-menu li li li.current_page_parent a {
    background-color: TEAL;
}
```